# How to get bluetooth mac address from local pc?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, mac-address

I want to get the mac address of the bluetooth device on the pc my application is running on.

I have tried the following:

```
private void GetMacAddress()
{
     string macAddresses = "";
     foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
     {
          if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
          {
               macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
               Console.WriteLine(macAddresses);
          }
     }
}
```

But the output does not match with 'ipconfig /all' in commandprompt. It does not print my blueotths mac address.
Any solutions?

I am ready to parse the output I get from 'ipconfig /all' but how do I get the output as a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use WMI to get the results. Herewith a link to a WMI solution that trails through the network devices.

I'm posting the code here in case the website is down, but all credit goes to the original author, PsychoCoder.
[Use WMI to get MAC Address in C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1727.htm)

And the code:

```
//Namespace reference
using System.Management;

/// <summary>
/// Returns MAC Address from first Network Card in Computer
/// </summary>
/// <returns>MAC Address in string format</returns>
public string FindMACAddress()
{
    //create out management class object using the
    //Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class to get the attributes
    //af the network adapter
    ManagementClass mgmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    //create our ManagementObjectCollection to get the attributes with
    ManagementObjectCollection objCol = mgmt.GetInstances();
    string address = String.Empty;
    //My modification to the code
    var description = String.Empty;
    //loop through all the objects we find
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in objCol)
    {
        if (address == String.Empty)  // only return MAC Address from first card
        {
            //grab the value from the first network adapter we find
            //you can change the string to an array and get all
            //network adapters found as well
            if ((bool)obj["IPEnabled"] == true)
            {
                address = obj["MacAddress"].ToString();
                description = obj["Description"].ToString();
            }
        }
       //dispose of our object
       obj.Dispose();
    }
    //replace the ":" with an empty space, this could also
    //be removed if you wish
    address = address.Replace(":", "");
    //return the mac address
    return address;
}
```

Be sure to include the reference to System.Management.
In order for you to get the network device name, you can use the `obj["Description"].ToString();`

You can also have a look at MSDN regarding WMI, specifically to the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(VS.85).aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static PhysicalAddress GetBTMacAddress()  {

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {

        // Only consider Bluetooth network interfaces
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetFx && 
            nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211){

            return nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This still returns some Ethernet connections. Only thing I can do is filter for names/descriptions containing "Ethernet". Not ideal, but not sure of any other unique identifiers.