# Find 32Feet BluetoothAddress of local Bluetooth adapter in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth, 32feet

I am trying to use code sample for my case from 
[Pair bluetooth devices to a computer with 32feet .NET Bluetooth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802791/pair-bluetooth-devices-to-a-computer-with-32feet-net-bluetooth-library)

In this, xmashallax have mentioned local mac address. To get local address I am trying this-

```
public static BluetoothAddress GetBTMacAddress()
    {
        var nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in nics)
        {
            // Only consider Bluetooth network interfaces
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetFx &&
                nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && nic.Description.Contains("Bluetooth"))
            {

                return  new BluetoothEndPoint(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes(), BluetoothService.SerialPort); 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting error here "`The requested address is not valid in its context`"
`ErrorCode: AddressNotAvailable`

Can you please suggest what should be the right way to get the mac address of current local PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer for others who may face similar scenario.

Basically to create a Bluetooth endpoint you need a valid Bluetooth mac address of the adapter. To get the local Bluetooth mac address of local machine just use

```
BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.LocalAddress
```

so the above code will need to be changed to

```
  public static BluetoothAddress GetBTMacAddress()
    {

        BluetoothRadio myRadio = BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
        if (myRadio == null)
        {
            //     Console.WriteLine("No radio hardware or unsupported software stack");
            return null;
        }

        return myRadio.LocalAddress;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same problem, but above code is also not working for me. My error message is like "The requested address is not valid in its context ECD09F51114A:0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb" - AddressNotAvailable