An error occurred: The requested address is not valid in its context. 05B197028654:0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb
I am trying to transfer data using bluetooth running the following .NET core code. But I am facing an issue that is mentioned in the title.
 try
 {
     BluetoothClient bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();

     Console.WriteLine("Scanning for Bluetooth devices...");
     BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices();

     for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {devices[i].DeviceName} ({devices[i].DeviceAddress})");
     }

     Console.Write("Enter the number of the device you want to connect to: ");
     int deviceIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;

     if (deviceIndex < 0 || deviceIndex >= devices.Length)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid device number.");
         return;
     }

     BluetoothDeviceInfo selectedDevice = devices[deviceIndex];
     string deviceAddress = selectedDevice.DeviceAddress.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to {selectedDevice.DeviceName}...");

     BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(selectedDevice.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort);
     
     bluetoothClient.Connect(endPoint);

     Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully!");
     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
     Console.ReadKey();
 }

Following is the error I am facing :
An error occurred: The requested address is not valid in its context.  05B197028654::0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb
Apparently the SerialPort is not working. I want to make this SerialPort working. Usually the SerialPort UUID is 0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb

Do you happen to be using the 32feet library? If so, you should use the tag "32feet".

The error is either occurring on the endpoint or when you connect.  Is the endpoint returning a valid response?  If you are getting a valid endpoint than the connect is failing.  Check the manual for the bluetooth device to make sure you are accessing a valid address.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836561/trouble-connecting-to-known-bluetooth-device
